# Can I hide a drive from the filesharing network, even from admin acct?

Tags: network, file-sharing, privacy

OSX 10.10

I have an external USB drive mounted on my computer. Can that drive be hidden from the network? If I want to make it invisible to another user on a different mac on the network (even with admin credentials to my computer) that can still otherwise connect to me and mount my internal drive, etc.

Just so it wouldn't show up in a finder window after the remote admin connects to my computer?

Comment: Generally anything you could do with an admin account could be undone by another admin.

Comment: It's fine if I can even hide it completely and just access it directly with "go to folder". I've tried the command `chflags hidden` but it doesn't seem to work s nicely on whole volumes like it does on individual folders

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... interesting question. I haven't tried this personally but it looks like you can edit `/etc/fstab` and add the UUID of the disk with the 'noauto' flag:

http://www.radiotope.com/content/os-x-hiding-and-mounting-partition

I was going to propose changing permissions to prevent the other user from having access to the files. But, as tubedogg mentioned, if the user is an admin they can undo anything you've done.

Perhaps it's best to eject it when you're done if you're concerned about other admins having access to the data?